# Image album. the select doesnt work?

Tags: php, mysqli

Im trying to make a album with next/previous image. The first image(else statement) shows but the image url doesnt get switched when i press next/last.How can i solve this?

```
$next= $_POST['next'];
$last= $_POST['last'];

if($last== "last" ){
  $result=mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM album WHERE user_id='$id' AND (time_added>'$time') ORDER BY time_added DESC LIMIT 1");
  $row=mysqli_fetch_array($result);
  $time = $row['time_added']; //Y-m-d H:i:s
  $url = $row['img_url'];
}
else if($next== "next"){
  $result=mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM album WHERE user_id='$id' ORDER BY time_added DESC AND (time_added<'$time') LIMIT 1");
  $row=mysqli_fetch_array($result);
  $time = $row['time_added'];
  $url = $row['img_url'];
}
else{
  $result=mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM album WHERE user_id='$id' ORDER BY time_added DESC LIMIT 1");
  $row=mysqli_fetch_array($result);
  $url = $row['img_url'];
  $time = $row['time_added'];
}
```

Comment: You forgot to add ORDER BY in your queries, without it mySQL will throw whatever it finds lower or larger than the given date without sorting.

Comment: Hm i cant change image at all after adding this

Comment: Why not? You cannot assume that you always have a 'Next' & 'Previous' Images for example if you're in the first image you don't have any previous images & when you're in the last images the next image isn't available. just add an order by for your queries.

Comment: @ahmad do you know why i cant get the $url to the href?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're struggling with more than your code so here's my detailed answer.

You have an image with a url like this `/pictures/view/$id` when loading this image, You'll need to run both queries to get the 'Next', 'Previous' Pictures & pass their values to the view e.g: `$data['Next'] = $this->pictures_model->get_next($id);`

Now in your view, When you show the picture, You'll go ahead and add something like this

`<?php if ( ! empty($Next) ) echo anchor("pictures/view/{$Next->id}", "Next"); ?>`

This does not require you to use POST method nor requires any extra effort as You're using the same mechanism you used to display the current image to display the next or previous one.

As for your queries; you'll need to add the order by to get the closest image that have a `current image date > date < current image date` that's one for the next & the other for the previous ... these values shouldn't be always available (when you're on the first image there's no previous & when you're on the last image there's no next and if a user has 1 picture only, both would be empty).